# how can checked radio on ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In ajax response I am tryint to create dynamic radio buttons based on the AJAX response.

```
success: function(data) {

    var obj = data.result;

    html = '';
    html += '<div >';
    $.each(obj, function(i, val) {


      html += '<input type="radio" name=' + val.id + '><label class="">Yes</label>';



    })
    html += '</div>';

    $('#where_toadd').html(html);
}
```

For each `val` in the response, I would like to generate a HTML structure as shown in the AJAX handler. The checkbox with the label `Yes` must be checked if the `data.id` of that item is present in the comma separated string `val.checked`. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve? do you want all 'Yes' radiobutton to be checked?

Comment: yes i want which values i am getting in va.checked that yes radio button should be checked

Comment: is `val.checked` an array or value?

Comment: values i didnt find the way to convert it ino array in jquery..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes here

```
success: function(data) {

    var obj = data.result;

    html = '';
    html += '<div class="form-group">';
    $.each(obj, function(i, val) {

      html += '<input type="radio" name=' + val.id + ' '+((val.checked || '').split(',').indexOf(`${val.id}`) !== -1 ? 'checked' : '')+'><label class="">Yes</label>';

    })
    html += '</div>';

    $('#ids').html(html);
```

Comment: @Shruti updated, check now, sample you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/rcqcn291/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to insert the `checked` attribute if `val.checked` is true.

```
function success(data) {

    var obj = data.result;

    html = '';
    html += '<div class="form-group">';
    $.each(obj, function (i, val) {

        html += '<input type="radio" name="' + val.id +'" '+ (val.checked.spilt(',').indexOf(""+val.id) > -1? 'checked':'') +'><label class="">Yes</label>';


    })
    html += '</div>';

    $('#ids').html(html);
}
```

Comment: When you say `1,3,4` do you mean the index value `i` or the `val.id`? Also, is `val.checked` an array?

Comment: Have updated my answer assuming `val.checked` is an array like `[1,3,4]` and `val.id` is also an integer. Now checkboxes are checked only if `val.id` is present in `val.checked`

Comment: not working... how can we convert that string into array maybe tha is the main problem cos maybe its a string instead of array

Comment: Can you please edit the question to show us sample structure of the response? You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.result))` in your handler to get this easily

Comment: @Shruti Thanks. Have updated my answer. Should work now. Good luck

Comment: not working its hide my all radio .. when i remove this line from ur code :+ val.id +' '+ (val.checked.spilt(',').indexOf(""+val.id) > -1? 'checked':'') + dropdown showing me again

Comment: Chirag Ravindra@ whats going wrong now in this code??

Comment: @Shruti it's hard to figure out what is wrong without being able to test it. It could be missing quotes around `name=val.id` have updated anaswer. Please check and let me know